# How to interact with a dynamically found Window Using PyWinAuto

Tags: python-3.x, automation, pywinauto

Once my PyWinAuto script finishes installing a program the program will automatically open up a new window that I wish to interact with in my next method. However, this window name contains a version number which will change over time. Thus I connect to the app using regex. However, once I've connected to the app how do I start clicking things within the window? Normally it is required to know the title name but the title name could change if the program updates to a new version number.

I.e.

```
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend='uia')
app.connect(title_re="A Program Name  .*", control_type="Window", timeout=600)

# Cannot do because we don't know the full title.
#app.AProgramName100.AButtonName.click()
#app.AProgramName100.AnotherButtonName.click()
```

**Things I tried:**
Many things but the main thing I tried was to: find the window, set the window title (AKA handle?) to a variable, and then where I would normally input the WindowTitleName I input the variable_name instead as seen in a brief example below.

```
# Trying to detect something like "A Program Free  1.0.0"
window_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re=r'A Program Free  .*', class_name='Window')

app.connect(title=window_handle, timeout=480)

# Remove all whitespace and punctuation.
window_handle = ''.join(window_handle.split())
window_handle = window_handle.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

# I thought the window_handle would be something like "AProgramFree100" by now.
app.window_handle.child_window(title="Get started", control_type="Button").click()
```

Final Note: 3 of the lines of code from above are from other stackoverflow posts. I did not provide links within the code blocks because Stackoverflow did not allow them but my actual code does provide credit.

Feedback would be greatly appreciated. Have spent all day trying to figure this out. Thank you!

---

**EDIT:**
I cannot fully reply to Vasily in comments so I am doing below this line.

Vasily's solution makes much more sense than what I was trying to do. Unfortunately, when trying to click the button it does not do anything. Code below.

```
app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend='uia')
app.connect(title_re=self.program_title_regex)
program_title_regex = "A Program Name  .*"

# Vasily Ryabov's suggested solution
app.window(title_re=program_title_regex, control_type="Window").child_window(title="Get started", control_type="Button").click()

# Suggested solution modified to specify what print_control_identifiers() stated:
#app.window(title_re=program_title_regex, control_type="Window").child_window(title="Get started", auto_id="popUpOnboardingWizard.pageWelcome.buttonGetStarted", control_type="Button").wait("enabled", timeout=600).click()
# Neither suggested solutions will click the button.
```

Also could you please provide me with an example of how to use .wrapper_object()? I tried doing so but it did not print any information. I'll continue to look through the documentation for information on this in the meantime.
I.e.

```
app.window(title_re=self.program_title_regex, control_type="Window").wrapper_object()
```

Answer (score 1):

Low level API (`find_windows`) is not recommended to use directly (you don't pass backend param, for example). It's better to find the element explicitly by calling `.wrapper_object()` or `.wait("ready")` which returns a wrapper with all available methods for the already found control.

I still don't get what you want to achieve with your code. Maybe

```
app.window(title_re="A Program Name  .*", control_type="Window").child_window(title="Get started", control_type="Button").click()
```

is what you need? `.wrapper_object()` is useful for debug purpose mostly. In production code it could be omitted because 2nd level window specification (`child_window`) must be called from 1st level WindowSpecification object, not from wrapper object. While method `click()` is a method of the found wrapper. Hope it sheds some light on how it works.

Comment: What you're suggesting makes much more sense than what I was trying to do. Unfortunately, it does not click the button. Since I could not reply fully in this comment I updated my original post underneath the "EDIT:" portion to provide you code of what I tried.

Comment: Try `click_input()` instead of `click()`. It makes real click while `click()` calls an implementation inside app which may be empty. Also it's possible to list all attributes (methods and variables) of any object with built-in function `dir(obj)`.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply I've been busy and didn't want to reply until I had a chance to look into it more in-depth. Unfortunately .click_input() did not work either. I was hoping to avoid a workaround I had in mind because it would only work for this specific instance not future issues, however, I'll go ahead and give the workaround a shot when I get a chance and will update this post later.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution partially by accident. And it's not an ideal solution but it works.

The program I was trying to automate was very weird in that it would not respond to my click attempts using .click(), .click_input(), pressing the "{ENTER}" key, or referring to the button by a different name (I.e. "Button13"). I had tried doing all of them at once to confirm this and... it worked! But then when I tried the individual buttons or different combinations it did not work. So I believe it requires 3 or 4 of the statements I provided to work.

```
    # a. Click "Get Started" button
    # Click "Get started" button using .click()
    app.window(title_re=self.program_title_regex, control_type="Window").child_window(title="Get started", auto_id="foo", control_type="Button").wait("enabled", timeout=600).click()
    
    # Click "Get started" button using .click_input()
    # Line Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241648/8917072
    app.window(title_re=self.program_title_regex, control_type="Window").child_window(title="Get started", auto_id="foo", control_type="Button").wait("enabled", timeout=600).click_input()
    
    # CLICK ENTER:
    app.window(title_re=self.program_title_regex, control_type="Window").type_keys("{HOME}{ENTER}")
    
    # (I don't think is needed?) Try to click "Get Started" using an alternative way of referring to it:
    ##app.window(title_re=self.program_title_regex, control_type="Window").Button13.click()
```